# Can Firefox be made to accept third-party cookies from an AJAX response header?

Tags: ajax, http, firefox

I'm writing some code that makes an AJAX request to our web server. Our server runs some logic and then responds with some JSON. It may also respond with a set-cookie header:

```
Set-Cookie: our_organisation=[uuid]; domain=.our_organisation.com; path=/; expires=[soon]
```

It works in Chrome and Safari as far as I can tell, but not in Firefox. Firefox *will* accept the cookie if it's an image request instead. Am I doing something wrong here?

I already had a problem where I couldn't read the AJAX response on the client side in Firefox; this was fixed by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cross-site XMLHttpRequest?

If so, per http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/ `withCredentials` defaults to false so the "credentials flag" used for CORS is set to false, and then per http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/cors/raw-file/tip/Overview.html the "block cookies" flag is set during the HTTP get, and per http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/fetching-resources.html#fetch that means `Set-Cookie` headers are ignored.  Sounds like Chrome and Safari are just not following the specs here.

You can set `withCredentials = true` on the XHR object to send cookies.  But note that if you do that you have to list an actual origin in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`; you can't just use `*`.

Comment: @Cerales By the way, I reported the WebKit behavior to the WebKit folks, but they can't reproduce it.  Are you sure you're doing a cross-site request in Chrome and Safari?